# Rails - select_tag form helper is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I just recently started working in rails forms, and though I have scoured the api docs many times, I have not been able to figure out how to use it properly.

Basically, in my app I have a form to place a manual order (shipping). I would like there to be a select tag for specifying the state to be shipped to. I am working with an pre-existing SQLServer database, and the column I would want to display, and edit is :SHIPTOSTATE . However, when I go to edit an instance of an order, the form always shows "AL" and changing the state does not actually update the shipping state in my form. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

The rest of my form is working beautifully, as the form is mostly text-fields at this point. The text-fields update just fine, but the select_tag is still troublesome.

Here is a snippet of the code in question:

```
 <%= select_tag :SHIPTOSTATE, options_for_select(["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]) %>
```

Comment: I copied your line of code and put it in a form of mine, it seemed to send the chosen option, not just "AL". Do you mean you have a `:SHIPTOSTATE` `text_field` as well, and you want that to update with the choice from the `select_tag`?

Comment: Oh sorry @Clark. That was my bad with not being clear. My select_tag is displaying all of the states. Not just "AL". However, if I click on an instance of order that has a SHIPTOSTATE that is "CA" for example, it will display "AL" rather than "CA". And actually editing and updating a state does not work. If I change "CA" to "LA", nothing gets changed in my database. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does your application relies on a 'states' table with PK column, state names, state abbreviations, etc.?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using form_for to generate your form and thus not attaching the select box to the underlying object? Please post your entire form code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select_tag on it's own does not know which object you are attaching to. You need to provide a current value. You can do that with adding a second parameter to the [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) call.

options_for_select(["AL","AK"...], "Current State")

Then you have to explicitly look at the params[:SHIPTOSTATE] in your controller method.

You might also be using form_for. In that case you would want to use something like f.select and not use select_tag at all:

```
<%= form_for @your_object do |f| %>
  # ...
  <%= f.select :SHIPTOSTATE, ["AL","AK"...]
  # ...

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The f.select did the trick! The form is now updating. Thank you very much @msergeant. I was not working with an instance of order, which seemed to be why the select was static.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add :SHIPTOSTATE to permit method inside controller?

Comment: No I did not. I am going to try that right now. Thank you!

Comment: okay, @Panczo, I added SHIPTOSTATE to the permit method in my orders controller, but the problem persists. This is something I should have done regardless though, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with a model, using the conventions in Rails, it's rare that you'd use the `select_tag` helper - you'd usually use the `select` helper, something like this:

```
= f.select :SHIPTOSTATE, %w[AL AK AZ AR ..etc]
```

If changing to using that helper doesn't work for you then you'll need to show us your controller, and perhaps your model schema, so we can see what else might be wrong here.